# Query with difference returns no data

Tags: influxdb

I've a query that uses `difference` function and I can't understand why it returns no data.

The query is:

```
   SELECT
      difference(FIRST(grid_power_counter)) as grid_power_consumed
      FROM homesolar.origin.main GROUP BY time(15m)
```

If I remove the difference function  it returns data:

```
SELECT
  FIRST(grid_power_counter) as grid_power_consumed
  FROM homesolar.origin.main GROUP BY time(15m)
```

[image: Results without difference]

Also, I can get results if I add a where time > now()-24h to the select with difference function.

I really can't understand that behavior. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q:** My query would only work if I add the where filter to it. Why is that so?

Quoted from influxdb's `Groupby time` doc:

> Basic GROUP BY time() queries require an InfluxQL function in the
>   SELECT clause **and a time range in the WHERE clause**.

I suspect your first `DIFFERENCE` query didn't work because it was missing the mandatory `WHERE` filter for the `Groupby time(...)` function.

The `Group by time()` clause could be returning no rows and hence not.

This could potentially be a [github issue](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb) for the influx team as I think their  query parser should be complaining to you about the missing `where` filter for `Group by time`.

**References:**
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/query_language/data_exploration/#the-group-by-clause